# Is there any way to only encrypt the api key in a GET oraclize query

Tags: solidity, oracles

I am building a contract that uses oraclize to query an API. The API only accepts GET requests (no POST) and also has authentication that requires an API key to be sent as an argument(query_token) in the query string.

Is there any way to use `oraclize_query` and encrypt only the API key leaving the base part of the url (such as `https://testingfire.com/transaction/15`) exposed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to Oraclize support and managed to figure it out.

For partially encrypted queries, I need to use "nested" as the base datasource. Then the key I encrypted using the python2 script from [this repo](https://github.com/oraclize/encrypted-queries), is processed using the "decrypt" datasource, which is nested in a "URL" datasource.

Here's a link showing the complete query: [Link](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#bmVzdGVk:W1VSTF0gaHR0cHM6Ly9odHRwYmluLm9yZy9nZXQ/YXBpLWtleT0ke1tkZWNyeXB0XSBCQStjUkFCek9vTnVHZnRIRnU0WlBKdzJKQVEzVFV0cDgwbHMzN2syc2dNcmhzOHFBdGVuQzkyZzVvYysvNTdPQkN2Um9aT0lXR3ZFaXpZQXFBcm5lcUFKK0lFN1RaaHhtWWhSZGMrdnQzU1ViMTBiTDcrS0s5R3ZLVGJjcUNEL1NEQVQvSTg0R1E9PX0g:ZW5jcnlwdA==)

Comment: thanks for sharing the link. Oraclize has added elaborating on partial encryption in its datasource. If you could edit your answer and add that one needs to use the nested datasource type, alongside the encrypt/decrypt datasource and whichever other core datasource they are using, so I don't post any duplicate answers and you already provided a proper link :).